# Detecting when a BackgroundWorker has its job done? Depending on circumstances, it needs to be rerun

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous, backgroundworker, filesystemwatcher

My class watches a directory for incoming files. It does do so with a `FileSystemWatcher` object, only monitoring the `FSW`'s `Created` events.

On a `Created` event, I start a potentially time-consuming process (file-deserialization is needed, sending an event to the client using my class, in which all sorts of things might happen). Thus, I start a `BackgroundWorker` object to do all this work, ultimately culminating in the received file's removal.

However, during all this work, new files may appear. In the `Created` event I check, if the `BGW` is still busy, and if so, I just store the fully qualified name in a queue for later consumption.

```
Public Sub New(Path As String)
    FSM = New FileSystemWatcher
    With FSW
        .Path = Path
        AddHandler .Created, AddressOf pFileArrived
    End With

    BGW = New BackgroundWorker
    With BGW
        .WorkerReportsProgress = False
        .WorkerSupportsCancellation = False
        AddHandler .DoWork, AddressOf BGW_DoWork
        AddHandler .RunWorkerCompleted,
            AddressOf BGW_RunWorkerCompleted
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub pFileArrived(sender As Object, e As FileSystemEventArgs)
    pNotifyClient(e.FullPath)
End Sub

Private Sub pNotifyClient(sFullPath As String)
    If Not BGW.IsBusy Then
        BGW.RunWorkerAsync(sFullPath)
    Else
        MyQueue.Enqueue(sFullPath)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub BGW_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object,
    ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

    '...
End Sub
```

But how can I find out, when the `BGW` is done?

I know, that there is the `RunWorkerCompleted` event. However, this event is fired from a real `BGW` instance still existing, so I can not go on and simply call it again from within the event handler.

```
Private Sub BGW_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object,
    e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)

    'This won't work.
    If MyQueue.Count > 0 Then
        BGW.RunWorkerAsync(MyQueue.Dequeue)
    End If
End Sub
```

What is the proper way of doing such things? Initializing a timer does spring to mind, but it doesn't seem right. (How much time should I give it? Should I loop for the `BGW` thread's end?)

Or should I consider another approach than invoking a BGW?

Comment: Instead of trying to work out when the BGW has finished in order to start again, why not just not let it finish? To do that you'd put the contents of your `DoWork` event handler inside a `Do` or `While` loop and only exit that loop when the queue is empty. There's a small chance that the FSW will add to the queue between the end of that loop and the `IsBusy` property being set back to `False`.  It's a tiny chance though, and that item will be porcessed next time anyway. You could also use some thread synchronization to prevent it altogether if you're really keen.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, this was my initial attempt, which I abandoned exactly because of this tiny (is it?) chance: it might be minutes until the next `FSW_Create` event, but a client notification delay exceeding a few seconds is not tolerable. Which synching technique would you go with? I reckon I can not make use of an `AutoResetEvent` in my case, as was suggested below by Tanveer Badar, see comment there.

Comment: It is *very* unpredictable at what exact time you can do something with the file(s) you get a notification for.  Almost never at the exact time you get the notification because the file is still being modified by the process.  When it closes the file is unknowable.  You need a producer/consumer scenario with thread-safe queue in which you stuff strings.  The consumer can be a BGW that periodically tries to empty the queue.  A timer is therefore the correct approach.

Comment: @HansPassant, I will go with this approach, thanks. How would I figure out if the file is accessible? Is trying to open it in a Try-Catch block the only (wasteful) possibility?

Comment: You already know how to do it.  There is no File.IsLocked() method, that is not atomic.  Waste is a non-issue in code that does anything with a file system, such code always runs at millisecond pace.

Comment: I still wish to take a shot at this problem when I get home. However, I feel that the comment @HansPassant wrote should already give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to nuke this problem from the orbit, put an `AutoResetEvent(false)` somewhere and your BGW's last task should be to `evt.Set()` and your main thread can do `evt.WaitOne(0)` to just query the status. If there's a possibility of running multiple BGWs at the same time, you need some data structure to keep track of which ARE is associated with which BGW.

A larger investment would be switch to pure producer-consumer design, which involves a queue (which you already have in a form) and consumer thread(s) to dequeue work items and process them.

Comment: The problem is, that the main thread does not execute in a loop or such: I have no meaningful place to query the background thread's status with `WaitOne(0)`. The `FSW_Create` event handler tells the `BGW` to start, then it symply waits for the next `FSW_Create` event, which could take minutes. Running multiple `BGW` instances is not really an option, because the order of the incoming files matters: they need to be processed sequentially.